# better way to start a delay in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to delay the entrance of an element to the viewable area of the screen, but the first animate is wholly unecessary, other than to start a queue that delay can then delay.

```
$("#top-message").animate({top: '-500px'},400).delay(1000).animate({top: '0px'},800).delay(3000).animate({top: '-500px'},800);
```

is there a more sensible way to do it?

Comment: You should "accept" more answers. It helps others know that the issue has been resolved, and is a small courtesy toward those who took the time to help you.

Comment: @patrick dw - Actually, I have marked as answered every question I felt has been, excluding subjective questions, where to award one right answer would be unfair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get it. If there's no need for the first `.animate()`, when why do it? If you just need an extra `400ms`, then add it to the first `.delay()`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/LFt4k/

```
$("#top-message").delay(1400).animate({top: '0px'},800)
                 .delay(3000).animate({top: '-500px'},800);
```

You don't need an initial `.animate()` to start a queue. [The `.delay()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) will use the default `"fx"` queue.

---

**EDIT:**

The issue you may be having is that if `#top-message` doesn't have an initial value for `top`, it will be reported as `auto` in some browsers. This value is not useful for animations.

To solve this, either give `#top-message` an initial value in CSS:

```
#top-message {
    top: -500px;
}
```

...or in javascript:

```
$("#top-message").css({top:-500})
                 .delay(1400).animate({top: '0px'},800)
                 .delay(3000).animate({top: '-500px'},800);
```

Comment: if I take it out, the first delay doesn't happen

Comment: I am assuming that it isn't delaying because no effects queue has been started.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - But it does delay. See the example. If it isn't delaying, then there's some other issue. For example, if you're trying to delay something like a `.css()`, it won't work without additional steps.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - ...ah, I know what the issue may be. It's not the queue, it is that if you don't have some initial value set for the `top` property of `#top-message`, some browsers report it as `auto`, which isn't use for animations. I'll update.

Comment: I am away from my code, so I can't confirm, but I am pretty sure top does have an initial state in the stylesheet, otherwise it would appear before time.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - I'd be curious to know when you get back to your code. It is strange that `.delay()` doesn't work unless it has an `.animate()` *before* it.

Comment: aha!! I had neglected to put the 'px' after the 500 in the stylesheet. Now it works!! Woohoo!!

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - Glad you got it working. :o) I see I did the same thing in my updated answer too. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it in a callback ?

```
$("#top-message").animate({top: '-500px'}, 400, function () {
    $(this).delay(1000).animate({top: '0px'}, 800, function () {
        $(this).delay(3000).animate({top: '-500px'}, 800);
    });
});
```

Example : **http://jsfiddle.net/Avinash/LFt4k/2/**